# Microsoft Access using and updating data in just one table

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2007, database-table

I need help, i have created a database that is made up of five table and they all depend on three primary keys such as contractID, Firstname and LastName. 
this fields are repetitive in all the five tables they are necessary
i just want to enter the names once so they could be recalled in the next four tables.
the only method i could find is the look up method but its not easy and makes work a lot harder for me. 
if someone knows how i could make this happen where by i could enter data once in one table then recall the names in the others i would  be so grateful and also be able to update them in one field where it will also update the other tables in the database.

Comment: When you say "contractID" do you really mean "contactID"? In other words, is that ID value simply a unique identifier for a person whose name is `Firstname` `LastName`?

Comment: When you say "repetitive", do you mean "the same columns exist in multiple tables", or "the same (combinations of) **values** exist in multiple tables"? Also, what is that "method you found" - on StackOverflow it is expected to explain what you tried to solve the problem before you asked the question.